# Transposing SQL Result

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Given that `Store` table contains `Revenue` and `Category` column, to find out what is the revenue by category I can do a SQL query similar to something below.

```
Store table:
+------+---------+----------+
| ID   | Revenue | Category |
+------+---------+----------+
| 1    | 60      | Toy      |
| 2    | 50      | Food     |
| 3    | 40      | Food     |
| 1    | 6       | Drinks   |
| 1    | 5       | Drinks   |
+------+---------+----------+
```

```
SELECT SUM(Revenue), Category
FROM Department
GROUP BY Category
```

I would then get the following result below.

```
+---------+----------+
| Revenue | Category |
+---------+----------+
| 60      | Toy      |
| 90      | Food     |
| 11      | Drinks   |
+---------+----------+
```

However, would it be possible to transpose the category column such that I am able to get the following results below?

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
| Toy_Revenue | Food_Revenue | Drinks Revenue |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
| 60          | 90           | 11             |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: That's a "pivot".

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Using MySQL for pivoting in any kind of general way is a notorious pain in the neck. Consider @Strawberry's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Toy' THEN Revenue END) as Toy,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Food' THEN Revenue END) as Food,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Drinks' THEN Revenue END) as Drinks
FROM Department
```